# AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'send_keys'

Tags: python, selenium

I am making a Twitter bot that can automatically login when I run the script. But whenever I run the script, I get this an error that I cannot find any solutions for. Does anyone have an idea of how to fix it?

I tried to change `element` to `elements` and `send_keys` to `send_Keys` but it won't work

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time

class TwitterBot: 
    def __init__(self,username,password):
        self.username = username
        self.password = password
        self.bot = webdriver.Firefox()

    def login(self):
        bot = self.bot
        bot.get('https://twitter.com/')
        time.sleep(3)
        email = bot.find_elements_by_class_name('email-input')
        password = bot.find_elements_by_class_name('session[password]')
        email.clear()
        password.clear()
        email.send_keys(self.username)
        password.send_keys(self.password)
        password.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)

ed = TwitterBot('EMAIL HERE', 'PASSWORD HERE')
ed.login()
```

I hope to get it logging in so I can work further on my project.

Comment: Evidently email and/or password is a list. Did you check what the `find` method returns? You probably need to get the first element of the list.

Comment: it returned the class names

Comment: Think, if it returns a list, does `email.send_keys(self.username)` make sense?

Comment: this is what i got ``Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "TwitterBot.py", line 24, in <module>
    ed.login()
  File "TwitterBot.py", line 19, in login
    email.send_keys(self.username)
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'send_keys'``

Comment: The first thing you should always do is to google the error message. If you do that, most of the time you will find a solution.

Comment: Yeah i did that its not that i was too dumb to search it on google cause that's what i do most of the time. i said that in the discription of my question too....

Answer (score 3):

<kbd>find_elements_by_xxx</kbd> will return list of elements and you can't perform the `send_keys` operation on the list. Instead you have to use <kbd>find_element_by_xxx</kbd> which will return a single element, then you can perform element based operations.

If you want to get the list of element and then perform the operation on any specific element then you can use below logic.

```
elements = driver.find_elements_by_xxx("locator")
# perform operation on the first matching element
elements[0].send_keys("value_goes_here")
# if you want to perform operation on the last matching element
element[-1].send_keys("value_goes_here")
```

Comment: If i use element then i get back this error ``selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element: .session[username_or_email] ``

Comment: Check if your locator is correct and make sure you have presence of element using `WebDriverWait` and ExpectedConditions.

Comment: this syntax is wrong for referencing elements in a list.  it should use brackets  `elements[0]`..

Answer (score 0):

I now know what I messed up:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time

class TwitterBot: 
    def __init__(self,username,password):
        self.username = username
        self.password = password
        self.bot = webdriver.Firefox()

    def login(self):
        bot = self.bot
        bot.get('https://twitter.com/')
        time.sleep(3)
        email = bot.find_element_by_name('session[username_or_email]')
        password = bot.find_element_by_name('session[password]')
        email.clear()
        password.clear()
        email.send_keys(self.username)
        password.send_keys(self.password)

ed = TwitterBot('EMAIL HERE', 'PASSWORD HERE')
ed.login()
```

On the line `email = bot.find_element_by_name('session[username_or_email]')`
it was first `bot.find_element_by_class_name('session[username_or_email]')`

Feeling stupid. Thanks for the help guys!